# How to make a switch change between two sets of text?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a switch bar change between two sets of text. I've got the switch and the slider working but can't figure out how to attach the funciton to the slider.

I've made testing environment using W3School:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVEFVIB1J6D2

The switch code had the formatting correct but its not taking the formatting for the graphic.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.innerHTML === "Longer text") {
        x.innerHTML = "Shorter text";
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Longer text";
    }
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #009bff;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2ab934;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(55px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(55px);
  transform: translateX(55px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <switch onclick="myFunction()">Choose your lenght </switch>
</p>        
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
<div id="myDIV">Longer Story</div>
```

Comment: Please, paste your current code in a HTML validator before everything. There's lots of syntax errors that should be fixed

Comment: Your code actually works but you've attached the click event to the `<switch>` element (which is not a valid html element but the navigator let its text appear anyway). Click on "Choose your length" you'll see. As some answers say, you just have to attach your click event on the actual switch, which is the `<label>` element below (your css is styling the content into a switch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to attach a listener to the input changes

```
HTMLInputElementObject.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
    myFunction();
});
```

assuming "`input`" as HTMLInputElementObject:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.innerHTML === "Longer text") {
        x.innerHTML = "Shorter text";
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Longer text";
    }
}

document.getElementById("mySlider").addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
myFunction();
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #009bff;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2ab934;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(55px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(55px);
  transform: translateX(55px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="mySlider">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
<div id="myDIV">Longer text</div>
```

Comment: I have removed Jquery. Shorthand code using jquery would be `$("input").on("change",function(){myFunction()})` @icecub

Comment: I know how jQuery works. It just seemed odd to add it to your answer while your code didn't even use it. Still I think using an event listener might be a bit too much for OP. He's clearly a beginner. Not to mention that your event listener would trigger on any input element. Which might become an issue in the future

Answer (score 0):

Your're almost finished. All you have to do is add an `onClick` callback to the `span` with the class `slider round` like this:

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round" onclick='myFunction()'></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick needs to be on the input element or span element like so

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

I also cleaned up your code for you since your style tags was inside the body and you had extra body tags and your elements were outside the html tag for whatever reason.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVEGHO8VCQJA

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the **onclick** to the **checkbox** with `this` as parameter.

`<input type="checkbox" onclick='myFunction(this)'>`

`this` is necessary to check if the checkbox is `checked` or not. If it is true than use the second text, otherwise use the first text.

#### Example for multiple usage

```js
var text = {
  1: ["Longer text", "Shorter text"],
  2: ["Another longer text", "Another shorter text"]
  // Add more
}

var output1 = document.getElementById("output");
var output2 = document.getElementById("output2");

function switchText(that, output, text) {
  switch (that.checked) {
    case true:
      output.innerHTML = text[1];
      break;
    default:
      output.innerHTML = text[0];
  }
}

function switchFirstText(that) {
  switchText(that, output1, text[1]);
}

function switchSecondText(that) {
  switchText(that, output2, text[2]);
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #009bff;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2ab934;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(55px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(55px);
  transform: translateX(55px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!-- First checkbox -->

<div>Choose your length</div>

<label class="switch">
  <input onclick="switchFirstText(this)" type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<div id="output">Longer text</div>

<br>
<hr>
<br>

<!-- Second checkbox -->

<div>Choose your length 2</div>

<label class="switch">
  <input onclick="switchSecondText(this)" type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<div id="output2">Another longer text</div>
```